# Upload Files To Google Cloud Bucket Using Angular Application

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

I have an angular application where I ask user to upload a file. My requirement is to upload this file directly to Google Cloud Storage Bucket. I have gone through the google cloud authentications.
There are multiple ways we can do this as follows

1. Using API Key
2. Using Service Account

I think best for me will be to use **Service Account** as per my use case.
From service account we need to create **jwtsignedtoken**  and then use this to generate **Oauth Token** and then we can use this Oauth token to call JSON API Provided by Google Cloud Storage

JSON API: [https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{BucketName}/o?uploadType=media&name=objectName.png](https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/%7BBucketName%7D/o?uploadType=media&name=objectName.png)

I want to do this complete flow through my angular application without taking any support from server side application.
(Signed JWT Token is obtained from only server side application) Unable to generate SignedJWTToken from Angular Application.

Can I achieve this completely from Angular Application and if yes then how can I do this?
Also am I doing anything wrong in above step or do I need to change strategy to Store File in Google Cloud Bucket From my Anguale Application.?

TYIA

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should be able to do it by using the Service Account ([Service Account email + key.json file](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed)). Please consider this is by no means recommended and that is why you will see the below message on several parts on the docs :

> ... it's easy to make serious errors that can have a severe impact on the security of your application.

Now, you will need to interact directly with the OAuth Server via HTTP once you have created the Service Account (SA) with proper perms (**be sure to limit the permissions you give to this SA**).

1. You need to meticulously follow the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) (click on HTTP/REST) .
2. When you get to the "Required claims" part, you will need to add the appropriate scopes for [GCS Write perms](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes) which at this very moment is 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write'
3. When you get to the "Computing the signature" part you need to use the key.json linked to the Service Account.

Now, the above is for sure not recommended. Another path that I would suggest is using and moving the app to Firebase + [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files). It would require a combination of setting the Authorization as [Anonymous caller](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) (Only accesible via Firebase) and "Authorized Domain" to only allow your domain. Be aware that if you follow this path, the bucket used by Firebase is the same used by App Engine so if you have an app running there you will be directly impacting that bucket.